# Finding sample set given mean and standard deviation

Tags: python-3.x, statistics

I'm trying to find sample set of 50 numbers from random range of 0 to 100. But I'm getting traceback error as unsupported operands int and float.

```
import random
import statistics as st

r = random.sample(range(0,100),50)
m = st.mean(r)
sd = st.stdev(r)

s = []

if m == 81 & sd == 11:
    s.append(r)

print(s)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Instead of `&` use `and`

Comment: As answered above, use `and` to make your code working. if you want values that are relatively close to a fixed mean and standard deviation, you can use `random.gauss(mean, stdev)`. This samples a (`float`) variable from that distribution. In your case you could do: `r = [int(random.gauss(81, 11)) for _ in range(50)]` (where `int` makes sure it is an integer). Note that the `m == 81 and sd == 11` is a very strict rule, since mean and deviations are floats (hence `81.00001` is wrong. Consider rounding the value before checking (in any case `round(m)` or `int(m)`).

Comment: Thank you @Thymen